# select query from mysql with order field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have mysql query like below

```
SELECT
p.prop_name,
p.prop_id,
p.star,
c. NAME,
pr.prov_name,
c.countryid,
c. NAME,
pr.provinceid,
r.room_typeid,
r.roomtype_name,
rr.is_promo,
r.price,
rr.final_price FROM
v_property p 
INNER JOIN set_country c ON(p.countryid = c.countryid)
INNER JOIN set_province pr ON(p.provinceid = pr.provinceid)
INNER JOIN room_type r ON(p.prop_id = r.prop_id)
INNER JOIN room_rate_promo rr ON(r.room_typeid = rr.room_typeid)
WHERE
  rr.date = '2015-11-09'
AND p.is_active = 1
AND rr.rating_status = 'ON'
AND p. STATUS = 1
AND p.provinceid = '5'
ORDER BY
  rr.final_price ASC
```

### and result show like bellow

[image]

and i want `prop_name` show only one row of each `prop_name` and get by minimum `final_price` column and order by `is_promo` to up

Comment: Looking ag documentation is a good start http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  Just add "TOP 1" right after your "SELECT".  So it would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1
/* etc... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **GROUP BY** clause to make the prop_name unique.

```
SELECT
    p.prop_name,
    p.prop_id,
    p.star,
    c. NAME,
    pr.prov_name,
    c.countryid,
    c. NAME,
    pr.provinceid,
    r.room_typeid,
    r.roomtype_name,
    rr.is_promo,
    r.price,
    rr.final_price FROM
    v_property p 
    INNER JOIN set_country c ON(p.countryid = c.countryid)
    INNER JOIN set_province pr ON(p.provinceid = pr.provinceid)
    INNER JOIN room_type r ON(p.prop_id = r.prop_id)
    INNER JOIN room_rate_promo rr ON(r.room_typeid = rr.room_typeid)
    WHERE
      rr.date = '2015-11-09'
    AND p.is_active = 1
    AND rr.rating_status = 'ON'
    AND p. STATUS = 1
    AND p.provinceid = '5' 
    GROUP BY p.prop_name 
    ORDER BY
      rr.final_price ASC, is_promo DESC
```